# How to access the folder outside public_html

Tags: web, hosting, web-hosting

I recently started to learn how to host my website, and I'm using a free hosting provider (000webhostapp). However, it always returns 404 error when I access the signup files within the app/view folder.

The index.php link: `https://mywebsite.000webhostapp.com`

This is the signup link: `https://mywebsite.000webhostapp.com/app/view/verification/signup.php`

Is there anything that I can do to actually access the signup files instead of getting the error?

The folder structures:

```
public/
  js/
  css/
  img/
  .htaccess
  index.php
app/
  controller/
  model/
  view/
  ...
```

Comment: move the app folder into the public folder?  I assume that is the document root on your web host

Comment: I wanted to keep the "backend" code (the app folder) outside of the public so that it's not publicly accessible as mentioned: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47199987/13367914

Comment: If you do that, none of your URLs can have "/app/" in them.  You would have to access your entire site through `index.php` and have it include your app when appropriate.

Comment: Facing same problem.  What solution did you finally arrive at?